# How to select one item after than remaining item should be selected automatically in recycler view android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need help in android recycler view.
I have to create one system like book my show sheet selection type.
So I have one number like 10, so when I select one item in recycler view.
So I have 10 number 1 item should I select manually, but remaining 9 items should be selected automatically select after that manually selected item. 
Like when I select book movie ticket for 5 people so we are the selective one sheet, then automatically select remaining 4 sheets same like I have tried to create in recycler view.
So please help me is there any example same like or anyone can create an example like this then help me.

Comment: Please put your code here of what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Create a SparseBooleanArray in the activity, select all the items on any click, and pass all the items of the recycleList to the array.